# Trying to get response from server with Ext.Ajax call in sencha 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a login form where I post username and password to the server and get the response for processing thorough an Ext.Ajax call. Below is my code:

**My login form**

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        id: 'register',
        frame:true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'userName',
                    itemId: 'userName',
                    placeHolder : 'Orgnisationsnummer',
                },
                {   
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    name : 'password',
                    itemId: 'password',
                    placeHolder : 'Lösenord'
                }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Logga in',
            minHeight: '45px',
            action: 'submitFormAction'
        }]
    }
});
```

My controller

```
Ext.define('GS.controller.Controller', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',    
    config : {   
        control : {
            'button[action="submitFormAction"]' : {
                tap : 'submitForm'
            },
        }
    },
    submitForm : function() {
        var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : "URL HERE", 
            params : { username : form.getValues().userName, password: form.getValues().password  },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function ( result, request ) {
                console.log(result);
                var jsonData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+ jsonData.msg); 
            },
            failure: function ( result, request) { 
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
            } 


        });
    }
});
```

**My simple PHP script**

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["userName"];
$password = $_POST["password"];



if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
   $response = array("success" => 'true', 'id' => '1');
   echo json_encode($response);

} 

?>
```

Problem is I get this response from the server:

```
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function (header) {
request: Object
requestId: 1
responseText: ""
responseXML: null
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object

Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong? Am I not posting the form values correctly or something?

Thanks!

/ The newb :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are POSTing two parameters:

- "username"
- "password"

...but in your PHP script, you're looking for these two:

- "userName" (note the upper-case N)
- "password"

I imagine that's probably the issue, though I don't see you decoding anything in PHP so that error message is a bit odd.

My advice would be to echo the username/password values from PHP to be sure they're being sent/received correctly. You could also set some breakpoints in your JS code to be sure the values are correct before sending the AJAX request. It's hard to say all is fine when I don't know what values you're actually sending.

Comment: Ah, missed that last night! Thanks!